# Cannot redirect to profile page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the htaccess code i am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$profile.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When the user visits his profile the url should change from http://domain.com/profile.php to http://domain.com/username (The username of the user logged in)

The error it gives is that when i type http://domain.com/lina it says page not found

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?

Comment: Its not changing the url

Comment: @JustinIurman so i can change the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thankyou. I i had enough reputation i would have +1 this but i am just starting

Comment: Glad to help out! Good luck with your project.